# Contextual action bar not showing sellection

Tags: android, android-listview, contextual-action-bar

I'm trying to implement a Contextual Action Bar (CAB) but whenever I long click an item it is not showing the item as selected (highlighted) so I'm not able to select multiple items to batch delete either.  Below is the fragment attempting to utilize a CAB.

package com.garciaericn.memoryvault.main;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.garciaericn.memoryvault.R;
import com.garciaericn.memoryvault.data.Memory;
import com.garciaericn.memoryvault.data.MemoryAdapter;
import com.parse.DeleteCallback;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;

import java.util.List;

public class MemoriesFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView memoriesListView;
    MemoryAdapter memoryAdapter;

    public MemoriesFragment() {
        // Mandatory empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        memoryAdapter = new MemoryAdapter(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_memories, container);

        memoriesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        memoriesListView.setAdapter(memoryAdapter);
        memoriesListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        memoriesListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        memoriesListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    private void refreshMemories() {
        Memory.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<Memory>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Memory> memoryList, ParseException e) {
                memoryAdapter.loadObjects();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        refreshMemories();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_sync: {
                refreshMemories();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Refreshed from fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
        // such as update the title in the CAB
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_delete:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Delete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // TODO: Delete item
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
        // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Memory memory = memoryAdapter.getItem(position);
        /*// Un-comment to delete item
        memory.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                refreshMemories();
            }
        });
        */
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), memory.toString() + " was tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-Hey correct me if i am wrong I found in your code that you are implementing **OnItemClickListener**   instead use **AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener** as you wants you action on **Long Click** item.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing custom adapter you need to implement Checkable layout for listview item.
Check this [Github page](https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/5245378#file-checkablelayout-java)

which explains implementation of Checkable layout with demo adapter.

Use in in your custom list item layout like:

```
<your.package.CheckableLayout ... />
```